# postgresql - find retention from video_call table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table:

```
create table video_call (
timestamp timestamp,
callerid int,
receiverid int,
call_length int);

insert into video_call values
('2018-12-12 01:01:01', 1, 2, 3),
('2019-01-01 01:01:01', 1, 3, 5),
('2019-01-01 01:01:01', 2, 4, 3),
('2019-01-01 01:01:01', 5, 6, 3),
('2019-01-02 01:01:01', 3, 4, 3),
('2019-01-02 01:01:01', 1, 4, 3),
('2019-01-03 01:01:01', 3, 5, 3),
('2019-01-03 01:01:01', 2, 5, 3),
('2019-01-04 01:01:01', 3, 7, 3);
```

find new users at `2019-01-01` and then get the retention rate of these new users for each days starting `2019-01-0` till `2019-01-04`.

The expected result would be

```
day          |   retention
2019-01-02   |     0.5
2019-01-03   |     0.5
2019-01-04   |     0.25
```

Explanation:

- on day `2019-01-01`, there are total 4 new users `3, 4, 5, 6`.
- on `2019-01-02`, there are 2 users (3 and 4) of the 4 new users make video calls.
- on `2019-01-03`, there are 2 users (3 and 5) of the 4 new users make video calls.
- on `2019-01-04`, there are 1 users (3) of the 4 new users make video call.

I tried but couldn't figure out a way to do this. Appreciate for any idea and input. Thanks

Comment: What results do you want?  What is the logic for the calculations?  I don't see this information in your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just updated the question and added the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want customers who start on one day -- say 2020-01-01 -- and then to see if they used the service on a range of days, you don't need a recursive CTE.  I would recommend:

```
select gs.date,
       count(distinct vc.user) as num_users_on_day
from (select user, count(*) over (num_customers)
      from video_call
      group by user
      having min(timestamp)::date = '2020-01-01'::date
     ) u cross join
     generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-01-04'::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) left join
     video_call vc
     on vc.user = u.user and vc.timestamp::date = gs.dte;
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @Gordon Linoff input, I get the solution as below:

```
with cte1 as (
select date(timestamp) as day, callerid as user from video_call
union all
select date(timestamp) as day, receiverid as user from video_call),
cte2 as (
select c1.user from cte1 as c1 group by c1.user having min(day) = '2019-01-01'),
cte3 as (
select gs.day from generate_series('2019-01-01', '2019-01-04', interval '1 day') as gs(day)),
cte4 as (
select c3.day, c2.user from cte3 as c3 cross join cte2 as c2)
select c4.day, 
       round(count(distinct c1.user)/count(distinct c4.user)::decimal, 2) as retention 
from cte4 as c4 left join cte1 as c1
on c4.user = c1.user and c4.day = c1.day
group by c4.day;
```

here is output:

[image]